# Symfony. Переход в production

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3

Пробую перевести Symfony 3 в режим prod.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что для этого достаточно убрать из адреса `/app_dev.php` и сбросить кэш?

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

После этого, заходя на сайт я вновь вижу дебагбар, где написано `Environment dev`, т.е. запросы идут через `web/app_dev.php`.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: проверить .htaccess?

Comment: @Ипатьев он оригинальный

Comment: у вас веб-сервер гонит трафик на app_dev.php, настройки симфони тут вообще не при чем

Comment: Ну так в оригинальном-то что написано? app.php или app_dev?

Comment: @Ипатьев в оригинальном все идет на app.php, но замечу, что адрес /app.php отдает 404, хотя сам фай присутствует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony тут не причем. Дело в Homestead (та самая ВМ от Laravel). Оказывается, если в `Homestead.yaml` в разделе `sites` добавить `type: symfony`

```
- map: site.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/site/web
  type: symfony
```

то ВМ создает конфиг под Symfony в режиме 'dev', где в `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.app` в `location` пишет путь до `app_dev.php`

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /app_dev.php?$query_string;
}
```

Это и стоит смотреть в первую очередь.

Answer (score 3):

**Настройки сервера**

Убедитесь, что сервер направляет запросы на верный файл в корне (app.php | app_dev.php). Для этого достаточно воткнуть в начало файла app.php `exit('true');`, открыть корневую страницу сайта и все станет ясно: увидели `true` - файл верный, не увидели - смотрим настройки сервера. 
Настройки сервера зависят от того apache или nginx вы используете. Если **apache** - смотрите в корне сайта .htaccess-файл. В нем, среди прочего, должна быть строка `RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]`. Если файл у вас оригинальный - там все должно быть в порядке. Для **nginx**, к сожалению, все немного сложнее и настройки должны быть забиты руками. Примерно вот такой блок у вас должен присутствовать в конфиге, чтобы запросы к корню попадали на app.php:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index app.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

**app.php**

Если запросы приходят на верный файл, app.php, но сайт открывается все еще в dev-варианте - нужно проверить содержимое app.php. 
К примеру, вот так выглядит код данного файла у меня:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

$apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . "_", $loader);
$loader->unregister();
$apcLoader->register(true);

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Обратите внимание на строку `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);`, в контексте проблемы она самая важная. Как раз здесь и устанавливается *environment* первым аргументом и *debug* вторым. Здесь у вас должны быть именно такие значения.

Кроме того, вероятно, вам для запуска prod-окружения потребуется выполнить команду

```
php ./app/console assetic:dump
```

которая генерирует всю необходимую статику. Но здесь ситуация неоднозначная, возможно, у вас система настроена на генерацию статики "на лету".

Comment: Дело было в настройках сервера. Спасибо за наводку.